# Almacenar dos números codificados en uno

Tags: python, regex, sqlite

Estoy realizando scrapes a páginas deportivas con el objetivo de almacenar datos en una base de datos SQLite. Dichos datos suelen tener el  formato `XX-XX` donde las `X` son números, y reflejan, para local y visitante, pues goles, disparos, corners, etc...

De cara a optimizar el almacenamiento (bajo la creencia de que es mejor almacenar un número que un texto), decidí codificarlo de manera que `XX-XX` quedase como un número que fuese capaz más tarde de decodificar.

Inicialmente pensé en `XX0XX`, y decodificarlo con la expresión

```
b='XX0XX'
re.split('0([1-9])',b)
```

Esto, por desgracia, he descubierto da fallos cuando por ejemplo, la codificación es

```
'Resultado es 2-0'
b='200'
re.split('0([1-9])',b)
>>'200'
```

En lugar de

```
>>['2','0']
```

Como solución, pensé en poner otro número como codificación, algo así como `XX27XX`, que realmente sirve para casi todo, salvo que decidas almacenar un parámetro que pueda ser 27 para algún equipo, como tiros a puerta, o ataques peligrosos.

Answer (score 2):

Este problema se resuelve fácilmente con teoría de información discreta, en tu caso puedes almacenar un resultado en un entero, tomando como entero un entero de `4bytes` (el tamaño por defecto para el tipo `int`).

Logicamente puedes dividir un entero en dos partes, (en tu caso dos enteros de `2bytes`), dichos enteros podrían almacenar valores en un rango de `0` a `6535`, por lo que podrías codificar los resultados desde `0-0` hasta `6535-6535`

## Codificación

Para codifica el resultado basta hacer lo siguiente:

- Obtener el par de números a codificar
- Crear un entero `r` e inicializarlo en 0
- Sumarle a `r` el resultado de multiplicar el primer número por `2^16`
- Sumarle a `r` el segundo número
- Devolver `r` como la codificación del par de números.

Ejemplo: codificar el string `5-3`

- `5` y `3`
- `r = 0`
- `r += 5 * 2 ^ 16`
- `r += 3`
- `r = 327683`

## Decodificación

Para decodificar el número se hace el proceso inverso

- Solicitar el entero `n` a decodificar
- Crar una lista de enteros `[a,b]`
- Establecer `a` como el número resultante de dividir `n` con `2^16`
- Establecer `b` como el número resultante de restar `n` con `a * 2^16`
- Devolver lista

Ejemplo: decodificar el número 327683

- `n = 327683`
- `a = (327683) / 2^16 = 5`
- `b = 327683 - (5 * 2 ^ 16) = 3`
- `[5,3]`

## Ejemplo en python

```
class Puntaje:
    @staticmethod
    def codificar(string):
        r = 0
        l = string.split('-')
        r += int(l[0]) << 16
        r += int(l[1])
        return r

    @staticmethod
    def decodificar(n):
        l = [0,0]
        l[0] = n >> 16
        l[1] = n - (l[0] << 16)
        return l

a = Puntaje.codificar('5-3')    # 327683
b = Puntaje.decodificar(a)  # [5,3]
```

Espero te sirva, saludos.

Answer (score 1):

<sup>* *Fue una pregunta con [autorespuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/113335/127), así que respondo a ambos*.</sup>

**Usar un número para separar números es imposible.** Para separar 2 elementos, hay que usar un separador que no pueda ocurrir jamás dentro de un elemento. Por ejemplo, si tuvieras almacenado a `1020304`... ¿Qué es? `1-20304`, `102-304`, `10203-4`, ó `1-2-3-4`... ¿Se ve el problema?

**No hay beneficio en codificar 2 números en 1.** No veo ningún beneficio en juntarlos, todo lo contrario, sólo problemas. Mencionaste que era para optimizar el almacenamiento, pero el tamaño teórico en memoria va a ser siempre el `[máximo permitido]^2`. Cuando son 2 números, lo mejor es almacenarlos como 2 números, en 2 campos de tu base de datos. Te va a evitar futuros dolores de cabeza, especialmente si quisieras buscar algo como: *partidos de un equipo con más de 100 pases*, *partidos con más de 3 goles de diferencia*, etc. Si tuvieras que hacerlo sobre el mismo campo sería algo complicado, y muy sencillo si están en campos diferentes. Además, SQLite usa un [sistema dinámico de tipeo](https://sqlite.org/datatype3.html), por lo que preocuparse por la definición de tipos de datos es innecesario.

**Sólo para saber, cómo se podrían unir en un campo.** Una opción sería ubicar a ambos en partes diferentes del mismo número, dependiendo el tamaño máximo permitido. Por ejemplo, si el tamaño máximo es 1000 <sub><sup>(entre 0 y 999)</sup></sub>, podrías codificar `123` y `45` como `123045`.

- Para codificar: `final = num1 * max + num2`.
- Para decodificar: `num1 = int(final / max)`; `num2 = final % max`.

Pero, de nuevo, no es la mejor forma, usá 2 campos.

**En cuanto a la expresión regular.** Usaste un split con `0(?=0$)|0(?=[1-9])`, y me pareció muy creativo, está muy bien. En aras de simplificarla un poco, en vez de considerar que el `0` esté seguido de un número que no sea `0`, o de `0` sólo si ese `0` está al final, podríamos buscar la condición: que el cero no esté seguido de otro `0` más otro caracter. Es decir, `0(?!.*0.)`.

Sin embargo, en estos casos, en vez de hacer split sobre un caracter con múltiples condiciones, es más sencillo buscar que coincida con un número, un cero y otro número, capturando a ambos números, con `(\d+)0(\d+)`.

```
import re

regex = r"(\d+)0(\d+)"

pruebas = ['600','008','1000','2004','107','1007', '1020304']
for numero in pruebas:
    matches = re.search(regex, numero)
    print (numero + "\t-->\t" + matches.group(1) + ",\t" + matches.group(2))
```

Salida:

```
600     --> 6,     0
008     --> 0,     8
1000    --> 10,    0
2004    --> 20,    4
107     --> 1,     7
1007    --> 10,    7
1020304 --> 10203, 4
```

¿Por qué `(\d+)0(\d+)` coincide con el último cero? Porque el motor de regex evalúa el patrón de izquierda a derecha, buscando todos los intentos hasta encontrar una coincidencia (o fallar en el intento). Lo primero que intenta es `\d+`, y como los cuantificadores son golosos (*[greedy](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#greedy)*) por omisión, va a intentar coincidir con la mayor cantidad de dígitos que pueda y luego, si toda la expresión no coincide, va a retroceder (*backtrack*) intentando con uno menos. Es decir, que el primer `\d+` va a consumir todos los dígitos, siempre que luego coincida con `0(\d+)`.

Por ejemplo, con `1007`, los pasos serían (sacado de [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/flZxGy/1)):

[image: debug paso a paso de regex101.com]

Claro que este regex separaría a `1020304` como `10203` y `4`, pero por eso es que te recomiendo **usar 2 campos diferentes**, y no preocuparte por cómo dividirlo con regex.

Comment: Sí tiene beneficio guardarlos como un sólo entero, si se guardasen como string el puntaje `200-200` requerirían `7bytes`, facilmente reducibles a `4bytes`. Y no, no es imposible, ver mi respuesta más arriba.

Comment: @Eduen creo que no fue clara parte de mi respuesta (avisame qué no se entendió)... No estoy diciendo de guardarlo como un string, para nada!!! Digo que le conviene usar 2 campos numéricos independientes en la base de datos. Recordá que en SQLite hay [afinidad de tipos](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html)... Por otro lado, si lees la parte de "*cómo se podrían unir en un campo*", verás que le estoy respondiendo lo mismo que le respondiste (sin operadores lógicos, sino matemáticos, porque me pareció más sencillo explicarlo así)... Y no creo que sea bueno unirlos, son 2 valores independientes.

Comment: @Eduen lo que digo que es imposible es usar un número dentro de la secuencia de dígitos, por ejemplo un `0` entre los 2 números, como buscaba el autor... No digo que sea imposible juntarlos (como comenté recién)... Y la parte final, sobre el regex, es una nota de color evaluando la expresión que usó, pero creo haber recalcado varias veces que no use eso.

Comment: En términos de indexación es más óptimo tenerlos unidos, después de todo en las consultas se solicitaría siempre ambos y no por separado. Aquí el problema es que no piensa guardar solo un campo con este esquema, sino varios, imagina que sean 12 campos con el mismo esquema, tendría que crear 32 campos si los separase, en 32 campos la indexación si tendría penalización y haría más largas las consultas.

Comment: Y sí @Mariano he leído más atentamente tu respuesta, error mío por comentar precipitadamente.

Comment: @Eduen En términos de indexación, según tu propuesta, ¿cómo podría buscar "*partidos con diferencia de 3 goles*" o consultas similares eficientemente?.. Por otro lado, me parece que son exclusivamente 2 valores, *local* y *visitante*, como menciona en la pregunta... Pero llegado el caso de que sean múltiples valores, recomendaría una tabla extra para esos valores.

Comment: No hablas en términos de indexación si no de potencia de búsqueda (nativa), las cuales son inversamente proporcionales. Una indexación óptima en espacio tendrá búsquedas menos potentes, e indexaciones menos óptimas tendrán búsquedas más potentes. Qué búsquedas en la BD se harán y cuáles no deberá hacerlas el OP de acuerdo a la lista de requerimientos en su fase de análisis. La búsqueda de partidos con diferencia de 3 se haría con operaciones matemáticas, se sacaría el complemento a dos de un extremo y se le sumaría al otro, finalmente se compararían con 3.

Comment: @Eduen Tenés razón, usé mal el concepto de indexación en el comentario. Creo que igual te estás refiriendo al espacio de almacenamiento, independientemente de cualquier índice, pero no estoy seguro... Y entiendo que se puede hacer la búsqueda, pero quería remarcar el punto de que es más complicado, menos potente en la búsqueda, como bien mencionaste... De todas formas, más allá del concepto de indexación que usé mal, ¿si tuvieses valores de partidos con estadísticas para local y visitante, realmente lo compactarías en un único campo? :-)

Comment: Todo depende de los requerimientos de la aplicación. Si la aplicación no necesita hacer distinción alguna no veo el problema de tenerlos en un único campo, separarlos en dos agregaría [complejidad innecesaria](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accidental_complexity) el cuál es un anti patrón

Answer (score 0):

Finalmente he encontrado la que creo es la solución correcta.

Voy a utilizar `split` con `regex` y lo que en inglés se conoce como lookahead y lookbehind expressions.

```
import re

a='600'
b='008'
c='1000'
d='2004'
e='107'
for i in [a,b,c,d,e]:
    print(re.split('0(?=0$)|0(?=[1-9])',i))

>>['6', '0']
  ['0', '8']
  ['10', '0']
  ['20', '4']
  ['1','7']
```

En la expresión `'0(?=0$)|0(?=[1-9])'` significa que tiene que buscar un 0, que es el elemento sobre el que hace split, que SI esté seguido `?=` por un 0 como final de string, o `|` que esté seguido por un carácter numérico del 1 al 9.

Normalmente pregunto, en esta ocasión he decidido compartir la respuesta que he conseguido por mi cuenta, si alguien tiene un sistema mejor bienvenido sea.

Comment: No uses un `0` para dividir números. ¿Cómo considerarías a `70108` por ejemplo? ¿Y cómo lo trata tu código? Si son 2 números, usá 2 campos en tu base

Comment: Quizá es que no entiendo bien, pero si tu lógica en `(\d+)0(\d+)` significa un 0 precedido por 1 o más digitos y seguido por 1 o más dígitos, no daría problemas en algo como '1007'?  Por lo demás si, si algún parámetro superase el valor 100 mi código deja de ser válido, es algo que no se me había ocurrido, por lo que me plantearé cambiarlo a columnas separadas. Un saludo.

Answer (score -2):

Personalmente yo lo guardaría en la base de datos en formato string. Además, tienes que tener en cuenta el coste de procesamiento en el proceso posterior para manipular el número.

Pero bueno, partiendo de que lo dejas así, lo más rápido de procesar a mi entender y lo más limpio es lo siguiente:

1) Lo guardas en BBDD como un número sustrayendo el guión. Ejem: 01-02 -> 0102

2) Obtienes el número de tu BBDD y lo conviertes a string con el método: toString(). ejem:

```
let n = numero.toString()
```

3) Extraes los resultados con el método: substring(). Ejem:

```
let a = n.substring(0,1)
let b = n.substring(2,3)
```

4) Puedes concatenar esos valores para pintarlos en la pantalla:

```
let element = // El elemento html donde quieres que se imprima 
element.textContent = `${a}-${b}`
```

Comment: Pero a la larga, con varias miles de filas de datos almacenadas, no hay diferencia en peso o velocidad de procesamiento entre tener ese campo como string o tenerlo como integer? No recuerdo donde o a quien se lo leí, porque fue a principio de año y no lo he conseguido volver a encontrar, pero me suena haber leído que había una diferencia sustancial entre una opción y otra.

Comment: Esto fallaría con números que no sean de 2 dígitos... Además, no encuentro el motivo para la recomendación de guardar un número como string